# Use prod enviroment on some urls, while in dev env

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I am using excellent https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle bundle for showing images. But when working in dev enviroment, generated urls become something like:

```
<img src="/app_dev.php/media/cache/60x60/somefile.jpg">
```

and when there are 20-30 images, my programs crawls. I also get lots of connection timeouts because app_dev.php goes thru entire FW.

Question:
Can I somehow set Symfony to generate production URL for some parts, while still in dev? Ie. that LiipImagineBundle always generate production URL, no matter what enviroment is?

Or how can I change .htaccess to use

```
/media/cache/60x60/file.jpg
```

whenever there is

```
app_dev.php/media/cache/*
```

found

Comment: If this is related with HTML output, and you need to use your `.htaccess`, you probably want to configure filters: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/filter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php(/media/cache/.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding (preferably before any other rules but after any redirect rules) this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php/media/cache/(.*)$ /media/cache/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works for existing images, it returns 404 when file is missing. Thanks anyway.